# Physical meaning of Ward Identity and computing vertex functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, greens-functions, non-perturbative, ward-identity

Following the derivation of Ward Identity by Weinberg book, you get it in the form

$$
(l-k)_\mu S'(k)\Gamma^\mu(k,l)S'(l) = i S'(l) - iS'(k)
$$

Can anyone explain the physical meaning of this identity? And how to understand it from this form?

$S'(k)$ is the complete propagator and $\Gamma^\mu(k,l)$ the vertex function.

**EDIT (after comments and with more details and questions)**

For instance, let's consider the following Lagrangian density

$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2 - (D_\mu \phi)^*(D^\mu \phi) - m^2\phi^*\phi - \frac{\lambda}{4}(\phi^*\phi)^2$

where $D_\mu = \partial_\mu +ieA_\mu$, $\phi$ is a complex scalar field( of charge $-e$) and $A_\mu$ is the electromagnetic field.

This lagragian is invariant under the Gauge transformation $A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu + \partial_\mu \alpha(x)$ if $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu \alpha(x) = 0$.

Suppose fields in the lagrangian are the "bare" fields. Then, I normalize them in a proper way and I obtain 
$$
\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_0 + \mathcal{L}_c + \mathcal{L}_{int}
$$
where 
$$
\mathcal{L}_0 =-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2 - \partial^\mu\phi^*\partial_\mu\phi - m^2\phi^*\phi
$$
and 
$$
\mathcal{L}_c = -i(Z_1-1)eJ_\mu A^\mu - (Z_4-1) e^2 \phi^* \phi A_\mu A^\mu - (Z_\lambda-1)\frac{\lambda}{4}(\phi^*\phi)^2 - (Z_2-1)\partial^\mu\phi^*\partial_\mu\phi -(Z_m - 1) m^2\phi^*\phi -\frac{1}{4}(Z_3-1)F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}
$$

where $J_\mu = \partial_\mu\phi^*\cdot \phi-\phi^*\partial_\mu\phi$

and $$
\mathcal{L}_{int} = -ieJ_\mu A^\mu -e^2 \phi^* \phi A_\mu A^\mu  - \frac{\lambda}{4}(\phi^*\phi)^2
$$
Then, I'm working with these vertices

[image: vertices]

Which is the vertex function in this case? Is it only a 3-point irreducible diagram? 
I should draw also the following diagrams (and more diagrams that I don't upload)

[image: vertex fnction]

The third is the vertex function as I found on Weinberg's book. The first and the second seems the 4-point Green Functions.

**Question 1)** Can you explain me the differences among the diagrams and can you show me the mathematical expression of the vertex function?

**Question 2)** Can I use the Ward identity and the gauge invariance to say something about the $Z$ factors on $\mathcal{L}_c$?

Comment: In general, Ward-Takahashi identities represent the symmetries of the system at the _quantum_ level; i.e., the symmetries put some restrictions on the Green and vertex functions. To understand the physical meaning for the identity above, one should see which symmetry it represents.

Comment: Could you give an example how to use the identity in this form?

Comment: Well, that's a very broad question, `user13653`! You can use such identities to reduce other equations (for observables) or check that an approximate vertex satisfies the symmetries (or conservations laws) of the system.

Comment: Editing tip: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic I just posted an example to clarify what I don't understand. Do you suggest me to open a new question and close this one?

Comment: No, editing is strongly preferred. In particular remove obsolete parts (only exception is if an answer refers to them). Readers interested in previous versions can click the revision history.